# "Организовывает" или "организует"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Писала текст и не могла сообразить, как правильно написать:
***организует*** детские кружки или ***организовывает***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот сколько раз говорил, пишите всю фразу...

Тут от типа зависит. Если там что-то типа ***Через месяц она Вам организует детские кружки [и Вы увидите, какой это замечательный организатор]*** — то тут при всем желании "организовывает" не получится.
Поскольку у Вас возникли сомнения, то будем считать, что у Вас другой случай.
***Имяреков Растакой Сякоевич активно участвует в общественной жизни, организует детские кружки... и проч.***

В этом случае, если нет опасения двусмысленности, то можно "организует".
Организовать — глагол двувидовой, может отвечать и на вопрос "что делать?", и "что сделать?".
Поэтому корректно будет и "организует", и "организовывает". Последнее используется сейчас только для снятия неоднозначности и в общем-то выходит из активного употребления.

Comment: Поддерживаю.

Comment: Сдаюсь без боя).

Comment: С Вами как-нить без боя обойдемся. )))

Answer (score 1):

ОРГАНИЗО́ВЫВАТЬ, организовываю, организовываешь. То же, что организовать в знач. несовер. вида.
*dic.academic.ru › Толковый словарь Ушакова*

Организовывает ЧТО ДЕЛАЕТ? детские кружки (постоянно и сейчас) и организует ЧТО СДЕЛАЕТ? детские кружки (в будущем).
Организовывать - глагол несовершенного вида, организовать - совершенного.